# TypeError: cannot pickle '_queue.SimpleQueue' object multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
async def main():
    print(message)
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    apps = []
    combs = batched(combinations, 200)
    chat_id = obtain_chats_id()
    workers = []
    print(f'~~~Parsing channel {chat_id} ~~~')
    try:
        async for i in async_range(num_workers):
            async with Client(f'session_{i}', api_hash=api_hash, api_id=api_id) as app:
                apps.append(app)
        for app, comb in zip(apps, combs):
            worker = mp.Process(target=get_users_info, args=(app, queue, chat_id, comb))
            workers.append(worker)
            worker.start()
        for worker in workers:
            worker.join()
        num_done = 0
        while num_done < num_workers:
            msg = queue.get()
            if msg == "DONE":
                num_done += 1
            else:
                final_set.update(msg)
    finally:
        save_excel()
```

When I try to run my program I got this error, have know idea what I do wrong.

The reason I need multiprocessing is that you can run pyrogram session in separate process.

I want to make several processes that each would start pyrogram Client in parallel way.
Then each process sends to the queue message with(set object with parsed users)

It had to start processes and then make final set of parseds telegram users, but I got error

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But a couple of observations: As a general statement, joining a child process and then trying to get items from a `multiprocessing.Queue` that the child process has written to can cause your program to hang. You need to get all the items from the queue prior to joining the child process. How do you know when you have retrieved all the items that the child process will write? (more...)

Comment: You cannot safely use tests such as `if queue.empty()`; this method is unreliable and , besides, you would have a race condition between the writer and the reader where the queue might be temporarily empty. So have the child put a *sentinel* item as the last element on the queue, which will signify that this is the last item that will be written. You *seem* to be doing that with testing for a 'Done' item but I can't be sure since you do not have posted enough code. (more...)

Comment: But the real question is why are you creating `Process` instances at all? Your async function will hold up all other async functions until the processes complete. You should instead be using the [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) method.

Comment: You are able to run pyrogram Client only in separate process or thread otherwise you get error that anothere client is already running since I have main process running Telegram bot and when someone calling the bot to scrape data from some group another process gets started and runs another Telegram session. More than one person can call this process from bot thats why I need processes

Comment: "You should instead be using the run_in_executor method" Could you say more about that ? Will my Telegram bot be able to run many other scripts in parallel using this ? Generally I try not to read python docs since it is unreadable for me since it is written in awful manner for person who trying to do it in first time